# Pjsua-2, Android - How to send media attribute with SIP INVITE request?

Tags: android, sip, pjsip, pjsua2

I am using  [PJSUA](http://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/)  library to build a VOIP softphone for android. I need to send a media attribute with the SIP INVITE message as: `a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000`
I tried setting it in SipMediaType as follows but it doesn't work.

```
SipMediaType sipMediaType=new SipMediaType();
sipMediaType.setType("rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000");
sipTxOption.setMultipartContentType(sipMediaType);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: To clarify, do you want to add dtmf attributes?

Comment: you need to add these in SDP message and it should be supported by pjsip.

Comment: @McLaLa yes........

Comment: You should handle RTP in SDP, PJSIP has already support for this in library.

Comment: @rya did you resolve this?